# How many types of starting sentences are there?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, writing

___ about payments and account balances should be directed to our billing department.

(A.): to inquire (B.): inquired (C.): inquires (D.): inquire

in the test, said was the right answer is **(C.): inquires**. I've taught how to start -- like in this case, must be To + V.inf.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your test is wrong.

Comment: And none of the options are right either. The correct answer is "inquiries" (note the extra i). The possible starts are of the form "[modifier] inquiry/inquiries".

Comment: Note also that **inquiries** is a plural noun, not a verb.

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired Your first statement makes a large assumption. As the Bard said, 'There's many a slip between cup and lap.'

Comment: I’m noting that one choice must have been *inquiries*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, I thought C) was correct because I misread it for *inquiries*. It might be a typo in the test.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it only requires one slip between cup & lap, and is very likely to result in a warm wet crotch;) I'm assuming it was a typo, but the aphorism is "There's many a slip between cup and ***lip***.

Comment: @gotube A typo in the test? As opposed to transcribing it from the test here?

Comment: @gone fishin' again No, it was intentional. Also, the proverb was introduced into English by Taverner, not Shakespeare. Demonstrations that it may be presumptuous to assume that errors exist prior to posting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - wikipedia would disagree with you - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_many_a_slip_%27twixt_the_cup_and_the_lip

Comment: @gone fishin' again 'An English translation of Erasmus' 1523 work by Taverner in 1539 rendered the proverb as "Many thynges fall betwene the cuppe and the mouth ... Betwene the cuppe and the lyppes ...' which is close enough.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - No mention of *lap* anywhere I can see.

Comment: @gone fishin' again  I threw in a deliberate mistake (2, in fact) to prove that posters can be the source of errors. It doesn't have to be in the original, even if OP says it is.